# Can't change default math font size inside tcolorbox

Tags: beamer, math-mode, tcolorbox, fontsize

Here I have a MWE showing that the font size of my text in math mode is not affected by me changing the default size using `\DeclareMathSizes` but is changed when outside my `tcolorbox`. What can I do to fix this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcboxfit{\myboxSlideBody}{
                    fit basedim=14pt,
                    % standard jigsaw,
                    % opacityback=0,
                    % opacityframe=0,
                    colframe=green,
                    height=5.9cm,
                    width=10cm,
                    valign=top,
                    halign=left,
                    right=0pt,
                    left=0pt,
                    top=0pt,
                    bottom=0pt
                    }

\newcommand{\framebody}[1]{
\vskip-0.25cm
\hspace*{-0.56cm}
\begin{minipage}{1.1\textwidth}
\myboxSlideBody{#1}\par%
\end{minipage}
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\f@size}{18}{14}{12}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
$\vec{G} = \left\langle x,y,z\right\rangle$
\vskip0.5cm
\framebody{
$\vec{G} = \left\langle x,y,z\right\rangle$
}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the preamble `\f@size` is `10.95` so you declared math fonts for that text size, but `\f@size` is `14` in your frame, so gets the standard setting.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcboxfit{\myboxSlideBody}{
                    fit basedim=14pt,
                    % standard jigsaw,
                    % opacityback=0,
                    % opacityframe=0,
                    colframe=green,
                    height=5.9cm,
                    width=10cm,
                    valign=top,
                    halign=left,
                    right=0pt,
                    left=0pt,
                    top=0pt,
                    bottom=0pt
                    }

\newcommand{\framebody}[1]{
\vskip-0.25cm
\hspace*{-0.56cm}
\begin{minipage}{1.1\textwidth}
\myboxSlideBody{#1}\par%
\end{minipage}
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\f@size}{18}{14}{12}
%\makeatother
\def\qqq{\show\f@size}
\qqq
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\qqq
$\vec{G} = \left\langle x,y,z\right\rangle$
\vskip0.5cm
\framebody{\qqq
$\vec{G} = \left\langle x,y,z\right\rangle$
}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcboxfit{\myboxSlideBody}{
                    fit basedim=14pt,
                    % standard jigsaw,
                    % opacityback=0,
                    % opacityframe=0,
                    colframe=green,
                    height=5.9cm,
                    width=10cm,
                    valign=top,
                    halign=left,
                    right=0pt,
                    left=0pt,
                    top=0pt,
                    bottom=0pt
                    }

\newcommand{\framebody}[1]{
\vskip-0.25cm
\hspace*{-0.56cm}
\begin{minipage}{1.1\textwidth}
\myboxSlideBody{#1}\par%
\end{minipage}
}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{18}{14}{12}
\DeclareMathSizes{14}{18}{14}{12}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

$\vec{G} = \left\langle x,y,z\right\rangle$
\vskip0.5cm
\framebody{
$\vec{G} = \left\langle x,y,z\right\rangle$
}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can reference it as a variable similar to calling `\f@size`?

Comment: @DavidG. no it is not a set of numbers looked up in the document it is a preamble command which is used at `\begin{document}` to iterate through all the math fonts declared at that point and set them up at the specified sizes.